# Count and group multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id | opt1 | opt2 | opt3 
1  | valX | valY | valY 
2  | valX | valX | valY 
3  | valY | valZ | valX
```

So i need to prepare the data for display a PIE Chart, it need to looks like:

```
id | valX | valY | valZ 
1  | 1 | 2 | 0 
2  | 2 | 1 | 0 
3  | 1 | 1 | 1
```

What is the correct way to write the mysql query? 
I think i have to concat all columns first but next steps?

Comment: Do you need this for a fixed number of columns, or dynamic? If it is fixed, then you can do this using control flow functions, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: In this case it is fixed and work fine with control flow functions. Thanks!

Comment: What is the best way if it is dynamic?

Comment: Well then it gets more complicated, because you would have to start with getting the number and names of columns the table has. In such a case, it might make sense to write a script that dynamically creates the necessary SQL query.

Comment: Fix your broken design. See noramalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN opt1='valX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt2='valX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt3='valX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS valX,
       CASE WHEN opt1='valY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt2='valY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt3='valY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As valY,
       CASE WHEN opt1='valZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt2='valZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN opt3='valZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As valZ
FROM TableName
```

Comment: You just  missed commas

Comment: Updated Thanks @OtoShavadze

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A normalised design might look like this:

```
id option_id option_value
 1         1 X 
 1         2 Y 
 1         3 Y 
 2         1 X 
 2         2 X 
 2         3 Y 
 3         1 Y 
 3         2 Z
 3         3 X
```

From here, your query is trivial.